# Can't access tempconvert web services

Tags: android, web-services

I am consuming tempconvert web services but it does not give any result just show blank screen.

Does that mean my app does not access the web services, or i have to some setting so it will connect to URL, i am using ksoap2 2.6.5 .

this is my code

```
package com.example.webservice2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;
import org.ksoap2.*;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

public class WebService extends Activity {

    private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
    private final String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
    private final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private final String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";

    TextView tv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

        SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        Request.addProperty("celsius", "32");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

            tv.setText("status:" + response);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

i am using web service from this url

```
http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx
```

Comment: Did you try to debug it? Btw, you shouldn't access web services on the main thread. Use an `AsyncTask`, or better, `Loader`

Comment: i have got javadoc not available message when i debug it, how i can add javadoc in it,i have tried to build path and add jdk 1.7.0 doc folder in it but it does not help and also used sum previous versions javadoc but that also does not work.is that problem of javadoc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometime when you are on the proxy network and not set the proxy setting than this occured check that you are not on proxy network.

Comment: ya you are right i am on proxy network,and when i set the proxy setting its work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use AsyncTask like below, this worked for me, if you face any problems let me know

```
 public class SyncroniseRecords extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{  
@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{  
    super.onPreExecute();
    dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();

} 
@Override 
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    // Things to be done while execution of long running operation is in progress. For example updating ProgessDialog
 }

@Override 
protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
{ 
       dialog.cancel();
}
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    /** Your Operation */

    return null;
}
```

}

This will launch the Activity without any Black Screen. Using onPreExecute you can display the Progressbar.Once the process gets completed you can cancel it in OnPostExecute().

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have given permission for internet if not pls follow below code

`<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>`